# Sixty percent of the time, my scraper works every time

Tags: python

I feel like a noob again after about a year of not coding.

I'm running a sel/bs combo against an investor repository; normal Friday morning stuff.

I see no reason for it to not work, other than it hates me as much as my teachers in primary school. I figured I'd ask you, the StackOverflow wizard, because you're usually helpful and much smarter than I. Here's what I'm working with:

I'm importing all the things:

```
import random
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Sending it to the URL, humanizing and scrolling a bit:

```
url = 'some link that doesnt matter anymore'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

while True:
    try:
        loadMoreButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(),'LOAD MORE INVESTORS')]")
        time.sleep(2)
        loadMoreButton.click()
        time.sleep(5)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        break
```

And returning the table for proof it's working:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

tables = soup.find_all('table')

dfs = pd.read_html(str(tables))

print(dfs[0])
```

All of the above works 100% of the time.

**This is where it gets interesting.**

After this, I try fetching a list of links:

```
target_pages = []

target_cards = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class,'vc-search-card-name')]")
for target in target_cards:
    page_link = target.get_attribute('href')
    print(page_link)
    target_pages.append(page_link)
```

**For some reason, it only finds these target_cards about 40-60% of the time.**

I have no idea why, and have tried multiple different selectors. Anyone here smarter than me?

Comment: Is it possible that the request may have failed or there was possible race condition somewhere? Also can you co firm that in the cases where the selectors are not found that they are present in the html?

Comment: This was basically right. The request was failing some of the time due to connection issues.

Answer (score 0):

After much troubleshooting, it's come to my attention that my internet was on the fritz. Thanks to everyone who gave me something to do while the technician came out and fixed it.

Comment: Questions that cannot be reproduced generally should be deleted. (You should be able to do that yourself presently, while none of the answers have been upvoted; after they have, it requires a moderator, or multiple deletion votes by higher-rep users).

Comment: I agree with you, but the dev overlords have seen fit to send me this error message: "You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it. For more information, visit the help center."

Comment: Ahh, shoot. Used to be that only applied after an answer had been +1'd, but apparently not so much today.

Comment: ...but, since there are now no undeleted answers with a score of 0 or more, you might try that again.